# Edit Microsoft Word in C#. However, a Word window pops up and someone is editing it

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, io

I am trying to edit a word file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word API (Sequence: Create a .docx file with nothing (Stream) => Edit using API => Save) But when the program is run, a word window pops up and this window appears. Says "(User) is editing and is locked." What should I do? (I get an error when I turn off the word window or click the "Read Only" button. (I have an office account))

code:

```cs
            string NewFile = rootPath + filename;
            if (!File.Exists(NewFile)) 
            {
                FileStream stream = File.Create(NewFile);
                stream.Close();
            }
            object end_of_doc = "\\endofdoc";
            Word.Application writing = new Word.Application();
            object fileName = rootPath + filename;
            Word.Document doc = writing.Documents.Open(ref fileName);
            //.........(Lots of codes)
            doc.SaveAs2(ref fileName);
```

Comment: have you made sure that nobody else is currently editing the document? (or that any lingering lock-files are removed?)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yes

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I deleted the file and tried again, but it doesn't work.